# jquery, javascript, update dropdown list options upon focus but retain selected value

Tags: javascript, jquery

Brain not working right now. Someone help me fill in the blanks here.

Need to select the currently selected value, repopulate the options, and then select the previous selection if it's still in the list.

To make it easier, the new value and previously selected value will have the same name attribute assuming it's still in the list after updating, and names will always be unique for the list of options.

```
//assume Options is a globally defined var for this example with format: 
// [{"display":"something", "value": "something's value"}, etc.. ]
function LazyLoadOptionsIntoSelect($select, options)
{
    //get current option


    //repopulate options
    $select.html("");
    $("<option>").text("--Select a File--")
                .appendTo($select);
    $.each(options, function()
    {
        var item = this;
        $("<option>").attr("name", function () { return item.display; })
                .val(function () { return item.value; })
                .text(item.display)
                .appendTo($select);
    });

    //select previously selected option if still in list

}

$(".lazyloadedselect", "#context").live("focus", function() 
{  
    LazyLoadOptionsIntoSelect($(this), Options);
});
```

EDIT: mistake in my code, unrelated to the problem, but still wrong

Comment: huuuuuuh..... hm, mine is not working too!

Answer (score 0):

If the option retains the same value attribute:

```
//get current option
var theOption = $select.val();
```

And later...

```
//select previously selected option if still in list
$select.val(theOption);
```

**EDIT**

You'll need to fix an error in your population code because none of those options actually have value attributes, which is probably why you can't properly set the value of the select:

```
$.each(options, function(index, item) {
    $("<option>")
        .attr("value", item.display)
        .text(item.display)
        .appendTo($select);
});
```

Please note `name` is not a standard attribute for an option element.

Comment: I tried that first, it highlights the option in the now open dropdown, but displays the first option as the value. Maybe something to do with the order everything is fired?

Comment: I've done the same before for cloning forms and retaining the value of the dropdown, but doesn't work in this scenario.

Comment: @Patrick: I've added an edit that has indicated an error in the original code's method for populating options that would prevent the new options from having values associated with them and also would keep you from updating the select's value with the previously selected item.